# "LINQ expression could not be translated" with DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I want to get users that match today's date(only month and date not year), but I am getting the following error.

I guess it doesn't allow me to use the "value" property of the Datetimeoffset in the query, how can I handle this?

Note:"BirthDate" property is DateTimeOffset, not DateTime.

```
     DateTimeOffset dateOffset;
     dateOffset = DateTimeOffset.Now.GetDayBeginUTC3();


    var data = await dbContext.Users.Where(x => 
    x.Birthdate.Value.Day == dateOffset.Day && 
    x.Birthdate.Value.Month == dateOffset.Month ).ToListAsync();
```

Error:

*.Where(u => (int)u.Status == 1 && u.Birthdate.Value.Day == __dateOffset_Day_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.*

Answer (score 0):

You can have the followings:

```
int day =  dateOffset.Day;
int month = dateOffset.Month;
```

then your query would look like this:

```
var data = await dbContext.Users.Where(x => 
x.Birthdate.Value.Day == day && 
x.Birthdate.Value.Month == month ).ToListAsync();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: its not working. I think the issue is in "x.BirthData.Value..." part but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: Then try:     EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(lx.Birthdate) which would give you the date in the query and then you can compare.

Comment: await dbContext.Users.Where(x => 
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Birthdate.Value.Day) == day && 
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Birthdate.Value.Month == month)).ToListAsync(); -- like this?

Comment: ef core not supporting EntityFunctions.TruncateTime

Comment: Use DbFunctions.TruncateTime instead of EntityFunctions